# Select randomly options from select and display the output accordingly

Tags: php, html, jquery, arrays, select

I have a select dropdown with multiple select. I am able to select multiple options.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="process.php" method="post" multiple="multiple">
    <select name="demo[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Demo1</option>
      <option value="2">Demo2</option>
      <option value="3">Demo3</option>
      <option value="4">Demo4</option>
      <option value="5">Demo5</option>
      <option value="6">Demo6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Process.php

```
<?php 
echo"<pre>";
print_r($_POST['demo']);
 ?>
```

I select `1` and `2` options and I am getting the output below output which is correct

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1 
[1] => 2
 )
```

Now my issue is, First I select 1, 3, 5 and then I select 2,4 options. so Is it possible to display the output like

```
   Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 4 
     )
```

After try matthias_h answer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The format of the Array output is a bit different from your example and could be adjusted, but the results are the results you're looking for.

```js
var selection = [];
var count = 0;
$("select[name='demo[]']").on("change", function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
    selection.push("[" + count + "] : " + selected[i]);
    count += 1;
  }
  console.log(selection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="process.php" method="post" multiple="multiple">
  <select name="demo[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Demo1</option>
    <option value="2">Demo2</option>
    <option value="3">Demo3</option>
    <option value="4">Demo4</option>
    <option value="5">Demo5</option>
    <option value="6">Demo6</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your answer and I added the output in the question. Please check it

Comment: I select the control button and select the option. second, how can I send the data to the process?

Comment: @NarenVerma Couldn't you add a hidden field in the form and set the value of this field to the array each time the select is changed?

Comment: You mean I have to use <input type="hidden" name="demohidden[]">  like this?

Comment: @NarenVerma Yes, though I have to admit I'm not absolutely sure if it works, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I tried and I am getting  but if I select 1 then I select 3 then in the array I am getting  twice data <input type="hidden" name="demohidden[]" class="demohidden" value="[0] : 1,[1] : 1,[2] : 3,[3] : 1,[4] : 3,[5] : 5,[6] : 1,[7] : 2,[8] : 3,[9] : 5,[10] : 1,[11] : 2,[12] : 3,[13] : 4,[14] : 5"> like the screenshot which I shared in the array

Comment: @NarenVerma You mean that the 1 is doubled when you first select 1 and then do a multiple selection of 1 and 3?

Comment: I mean, first I select 1 then I press control and select 3 then I am getting live above output

Comment: @NarenVerma It is solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/xqoypaek/ (check the console). It works if you select e.g. 1 and then 1 and 3, but it won't work if you select 1, then 1 and 3 and then in addition 1 up to 4.

Comment: Please check this screenshot : https://prnt.sc/t2bju7
I am getting this output in the console Array(5) [ "[0] : 1", "[2] : 3", "[3] : 1", "[4] : 3", "[5] : 4" ]

Comment: @NarenVerma I guess you selected 1, then 1 and 3 and then 1 and 4. Such a case is not covered by the provided solution. It would be quite a bit of work to handle such cases as it would be necessary to check the arrays previous values for occurences of some of the actually selected  values..

Comment: I try to explain in the all the comments that I select 1 that using control button I select 3 the 5 and so on.

Comment: @NarenVerma I understand what you mean, but you have to understand that everytime you select 1, then using control button select 3 or 5 and so on you make a single selection. It's normal that the result then contains doubles like [0] : 1, [1]. 1, [2]: 3, [3]: 1, [4]: 3, [5] 5 and so on. To prevent this from happening it would be necessary to check the array for the previous made selection and compare the values with the actual selection.

Comment: @NarenVerma The issue of the multiple selects is solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/xqoypaek/1/ This solution would have another problem if you e.g. select 1, then 1 and 3, then 1 and 4, then 2 and then 1 as the last 1 would not appear again as the array is checked for previous values and no double entries will happen at all.